# Getting the value of a textarea in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get the value of a textarea using jQuery that I will submit via AJAX but it is not working.

```
<div class = 'post_updates'>
 <div class = 'comment_updates'>
  <div class = 'commentdiv'>
     <textarea autocomplete = 'off' class='commenttext form-control' rows = '1' 
      placeholder='Have your say...'></textarea>
     <button class='comment btn btn-xs btn-primary onespacedown' value = '7' 
      type='submit'>Comment</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery code:

```
$('.commentdiv').on('click', '.comment', function () {
   var $this = $(this);
   var user_commnet = $this.parents('.commentdiv').find('.commenttext').val();
   var post = $this.val();

   //AJAX code goes here

   alert ('Comment: ' + user_comment + 'ID: ' + post);
})
```

Any help would be gladly appreciated!

Comment: there is a spelling mistake in `var user_comment = $this.parents('.commentdiv').find('.commenttext').val();`

Comment: Why aren't you using a `<form>` for this?

Comment: `user_commnet` instead of `user_comment `

Comment: other than that it is fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sD6DM/1/

Comment: @ŠimeVidas it is an ajax post...

Comment: @ArunPJohny If OP had a `<form>`, they wouldn't have to use jQuery for the DOM traversal (that `.parents().find()` stuff). Why use jQuery for this when the form API already provides the references?

Comment: also it can be changed to `var user_comment = $this.prev().val();` see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sD6DM/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny : Thanks! I gave up after tirelessly failing to find what could be wrong with code. Thank you once again.

Comment: see my second fiddle... does it solves the problem... if so I'll post it as an answer

Comment: @ArunPJohny But `$this.prev().val();` would break if the elements were rearranged in any way. The way it's done in the question is much, much better

Comment: @Shai any traversal will break if the markup changes.... so we can always go with the current markup... if you are planning for tomorrows changes then the class names itself can change

Comment: @ArunPJohny A better approach would be to use `<form>` + "submit" handler. Than you don't have to worry about markup at all. See my answer below.

Comment: @ArunPJohny that's like saying use [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants) instead of variables, because if you change the variable's name it'll all break anyway. Traversing up to a container element (by classname) and then back down to the desired element (by classname) is a hell of a lot safer than nameless `.prev()` traversal. Happy to continue this in chat, but I doubt there's much more to say on it

Comment: @Shai DOM traversal is not optimal in this case. See my answer. Let's use the built-in DOM references instead of jQuery.

Comment: @ArunPJohny `$this.prev().val()` is not working.

Comment: @user3009875 then your markup is not the same as what you shared... did you check the fiddle... else go with what you have already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem is a small typo, you've written `user_commnet` instead of `user_comment`.

Just that one change makes it work: [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rNZ6X/)

```
$('.commentdiv').on('click', '.comment', function () {
   var $this = $(this);
   var user_comment = $this.parents('.commentdiv').find('.commenttext').val();
   var post = $this.val();

   //AJAX code goes here

   alert ('Comment: ' + user_comment + 'ID: ' + post);
});
```

Also, consider using [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead of `.parents()`. Slightly faster/more sensible, as it'll stop once it finds the `.commentdiv` instead of traversing all the way up to the root and potentially returning more than one element.

Comment: `closest()` is not returning any value. It returns `undefine`.

Answer (score 0):

It must be

```
 $('.commentdiv').on('click', '.comment', function () {
   var $this = $(this);
   var user_commnet = $('.commenttext').val();
   var post = $(this).val();

   //AJAX code goes here

   alert ('Comment: ' + user_commnet + 'ID: ' + post);
})
```

See demo 
http://jsfiddle.net/haduythuan/fgjN4/

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and it works if you include that javascript code into the $(document).ready(function(){ ...... });

Also, change the variable name user_comment.

Like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.commentdiv').on('click', '.comment', function () {
   var $this = $(this);
   var user_comment = $this.parents('.commentdiv').find('.commenttext').val();
   var post = $this.val();

   //AJAX code goes here

   alert ('Comment: ' + user_comment + 'ID: ' + post);
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to use a `<form>` element and bind a "submit" event handler, e.g.

HTML:

```
<form id="form">
    <textarea name="comment"></textarea>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
    // get the <textarea> value
    var val = this.elements.comment.value;

    // prevent form submission
    e.preventDefault();

    // submit value via Ajax
    // ...
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/r5BYz/3/

---

My approach is better because:

1. It is markup agnostic. The TEXTAREA and submit button can be anywhere within the FORM element.
2. It sets up a foundation for graceful degradation. (If JavaScript fails, the form submits normally enabling you to set up a fallback mechanism on the server.)
3. Instead of unnecessarily using jQuery's DOM traversal methods, the form's `.elements` array is used to access its TEXTAREA element.

Comment: I actually don't form in that place that I am using the `textarea`. Wouldn't be unnecessary to use form when I am submitting the value via `AJAX` and I wouldn't have to border myself with disabling `Submit` in the JavaScript code.